# Magento 2 : Event Observer For Shipping Address Selection

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping-address

I am working on custom extension and need to execute my code when the customer clicks on "Next" button available in checkout.

I need an event observer in which, used shipping and billing address selected or added by customer.

See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: what about sales_quote_collect_totals_after ?

Comment: @KeyurShah already try that event, but not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? this event always execute

Comment: @KeyurShah can give me sample code using which, I get selected address into of customer. I need event only for this action not every time cart is reload or other function.

Answer (score 5):

You should use plugin to get the shipping info:

Your di should be under `etc` folder: `app/code/Extension/Vendor/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="get_shipping_info" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Your Plugin:

```
/**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    )
    {
       ......
    }

    public function afterSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $shipping,
         $result
    )
    {
        ......
    }
```

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: I am try above code, but in not called our function when we click on "Next" button.

Comment: Which is your function? the `saveAddressInformation()` function will be called when click Next.

Comment: I try to implement this public function afterSaveAddressInformation but not called

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: still it not calling.

Comment: `beforeSaveAddressInformation` is called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48259/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Comment: HI can you please tell mw how can i show the error message from the jsonresponse from the plugin .I set the message like     $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
        if($count==0){
   $response = [
    'errors' => false,
    'message' => __('We dont ship on this zipcode')
   ];
   return $resultJson->setData($response);
  }

Comment: @RohitGoel Because json response is for Ajax controller, so, in this case, we should use `Preference` to override the class.

Comment: hi i have use the plugin in my module , cant we set a json response or show error message  from there

Comment: @RohitGoel You should open new question. I will take a look at your case.

Comment: Please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219598/show-error-message-through-plugin-magento2
Thanks

Comment: @RohitGoel Ok, I see, however, you should migrate your question to Magento SE.

Comment: Please check here  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150947/show-error-message-through-plugin-magento2

Comment: @RohitGoel I see.

Comment: Can you check this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361086/magento2-some-doubts-using-a-before-plugin