# Magento2 - some doubts using a before plugin

Tags: magento2, before-plugin

We want to add some logic when Magento saves shipping information during checkout, so we have tried using a before plugin for `saveAddressInformation` method

This would be method definition

```
/**
 * Save address information.
 *
 * @param int $cartId
 * @param ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
 * @return PaymentDetailsInterface
 * @throws InputException
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 * @throws StateException
 */
public function saveAddressInformation(
    $cartId,
    ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
): PaymentDetailsInterface {
```

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php**

So, our plugin looks like this

```
public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
) {
```

Question would be, which data should we return during our custom code, if some validation fails? We've tried `return $subject;` but that throws this error, which I am not sure to understand

> CRITICAL: TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
> Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement::saveAddressInformation()
> must implement interface
> Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface, instance of
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentDetailsFactory given, called in
> .../vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php
> on line 58 and defined in
> .../vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php:158

**UPDATE**

I have read in devdocs we should return an array including all arguments (which we are not doing by returning only `$subject`) but if so what I'd expect would be having some error of null given for second parameter, and not that instance of **Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentDetailsFactory**

Not sure if I understand what's happening here. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am trying to answer your "Why" question. In order to understand it, you need to know how plugins actually works.

Every plugin we defines via `di.xml` file will use the Interceptor trait `Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor` internally. This Interceptor trait apply all `before` and `after` and `around` plugins defined for a specific method of the subject class.

Below you see the `Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor::__callPlugins()` method that actually will be called internally in order to subject the method for plugin modifications. I am just quoting the `before` logic you find there.

```
protected function ___callPlugins($method, array $arguments, array $pluginInfo)
{
    $subject = $this;
    $type = $this->subjectType;
    $pluginList = $this->pluginList;

    $next = function (...$arguments) use (
        $method,
        &$pluginInfo,
        $subject,
        $type,
        $pluginList,
        &$next
    ) {
        ...
        $result = null;

        if (isset($currentPluginInfo[DefinitionInterface::LISTENER_BEFORE])) {
            // Call 'before' listeners
            foreach ($currentPluginInfo[DefinitionInterface::LISTENER_BEFORE] as $code) {
                $pluginInstance = $pluginList->getPlugin($type, $code);
                $pluginMethod = 'before' . $capMethod;
                $beforeResult = $pluginInstance->$pluginMethod($this, ...array_values($arguments));

                if ($beforeResult !== null) {
                    $arguments = (array)$beforeResult;
                }
            }
        }

        ...

        return $result;
    };

    $result = $next(...array_values($arguments));
    $next = null;

    return $result;
}
```

> **Magento Trivia:**
> Ideally, before plugins expected to return array of original arguments
> of the method or a `null`.

Now let's debug what happens in your case. You can see magento loops through all before plugins defined. These plugins can modify the arguments as per their need. If a plugin changes the argument, then the plugins in the pipeline will be feed with those changed arguments.

In your case, you return `$subject`. This means `$beforeResult` is now equals to `$subject`. The magic happens in the next if condition.

```
if ($beforeResult !== null) {
    $arguments = (array)$beforeResult;
}
```

if `$beforeResult` is actually an array, then `$arguments` will be same as the `$beforeResult`. However, if `$beforeResult` is an object, then `(array)$beforeResult` will give you totally different output which will be an array of the object properties.

To understand this correctly, let's do this plainly with a test class. Consider following code:

```
class TestClass {
   private $property1 = 'my property';
   
   function __construct(string $arg1, string $arg2 = 'test') {}
}
print_r((array)(new TestClass('some')));
```

you will yield a result:

```
Array ( [TestClassproperty1] => my property )
```

This means you still get an array which will be the collection of properties of the object in the context.

So if we apply the same in your context, the `$arguments` looks like:

```
$arguments = Array ( 
    [ShippingInformationManagementPaymentMethodManagementInterface] =>  
    [ShippingInformationManagementPaymentDetailsFactory] => 
    [ShippingInformationManagementCartTotalRepositoryInterface] => 
    ....
)
```

Due to this, the next before plugin in the pipeline will have an exact same method definition like yours will be called like below.

```
$beforeResult = $pluginInstance->$pluginMethod($this, ...array_values($arguments));
```

Here the plugin first argument is `$this`. It is fine. Second argument would be `PaymentMethodManagementInterface` which is not correct. But it wont throw error as there is no typecasting for `$cartId`. The next argument would be `PaymentDetailsFactory` and it finally fails due to the typecasting issue in the before plugin which is in the context that expects `ShippingInformationInterface` there. Thus you get the above error.

**Take away point**

You can pass a `null` value if you are not changing the arguments altogether in your plugin. If you altered any of the argument in the before plugin, then what you need to return is the array of original arguments of the method

Comment: All clear now. Thank you very much

Comment: Here is a link to the Adobe Commerce documentation about before plugins with supporting documentation about returning null if unchanged: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/#before-methods

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\PaymentDetailsInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement;

class SaveAddress
{
    /**
     * @param ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param int $cartId
     * @param ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     * @return array
     */

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(ShippingInformationManagement $subject, $cartId, ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation)
    {
        // need to add custom logic
        return [$cartId, $addressInformation];
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Just update class name and namespace

Comment: Yeah, I'll try... could you add an explanation of the error I am having, so I will understand it better

Comment: I think main issue was missing `cartId` parameter. number of parameter should be same in `beforepluign` and original class.